# ZF1 CSRF Token Never Validating (Zend never finds the token)

Tags: php, zend-framework, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm having some issues with Zend's CSRF Tokens. I'm using ZF1 (Don't start).

Every time i submit the form i get an error message 'missingToken'. After going through the core i found that Zend never gets the token when validating and therefore is always null and will never pass.

Why would this be? How can i fix this issue?

I've looked at pretty much all the issues raised on this and nothing so  far.

The Form

```
    parent::init();

    $this->addElement('text', 'email', [
        'label' => 'Email',
        'required' => true,
        'filters' => ['StringTrim'],
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'validators' => [
            ['NotEmpty', true, ["messages" => 'Enter your email address.']],
            ['EmailAddress', true, ['messages' => [
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_HOSTNAME  => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_MX_RECORD => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_SEGMENT  => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::DOT_ATOM => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::QUOTED_STRING => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => 'Not a valid email address.',
                Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::LENGTH_EXCEEDED => 'Not a valid email address.'
            ]]]
        ]
    ]);

    $this->addElement('password', 'password', [
        'label' => 'Password',
        'required' => true,
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'validators' => [['NotEmpty', true, ["messages" => 'Enter a password.']]]
    ]);

    $this->addElement('password', 'passwordRepeat', [
        'label' => 'Repeat Password',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => [
            ['NotEmpty', true, ["messages" => 'Enter the password again.']],
            ['Identical', false, 'token' => 'password', "messages" => 'Passwords did not match. Try again.']
        ]
    ]);

     $this->addElement('checkbox', 'termsOfUse', [
         'label' => 'I agree to the <a href="/terms">Marquee Terms of Use</a>',
         'value' => 1,
         'validators' => [
             ['NotEmpty', true, ['messages' => 'To continue you please agree to Marquee\'s Terms of Use.']]
         ]
     ]);

    $this->addElement(
        (new Zend_Form_Element_Hash('token', 'csrf', array('salt' => 'secure')))->setSalt('my_magical_token')
    );

    $this->getElement('token')->initCsrfToken();
```

My Controller

```
    public function accountAction()
{
    //load form
    $form = new Application_Auth_Forms_Account(['action' => '/subscribe']);

    // Assign form to the view
    $this->view->form = $form;

    // Defensive post check so nothing below this executes if not submitted
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Defensive form validation
    if (!$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getParams())) {
        return false;
    }
```

}

View

```
form name="create-account" method="post" action="<?= $this->getAction() ?>">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">

        <?php $email = $this->getElement('email'); ?>

        <div class="form-group<?php if ($email->getMessages()): ?> has-warning<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="<?= $email->getName() ?>"
                       placeholder="<?= $this->getLocaliser()->key( 'email_address', 'Email Address' ) ?>" name="<?= $email->getName() ?>"
                       value="<?= $email->getValue() ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">

        <?php $password = $this->getElement('password'); ?>

        <div class="form-group<?php if ($password->getMessages()): ?> has-warning<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="<?= $password->getName() ?>"
                       placeholder="<?= $this->getLocaliser()->key( 'password', 'Password' ) ?>" name="<?= $password->getName() ?>"
                       value="<?= $password->getValue() ?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php $passwordRepeat = $this->getElement('passwordRepeat'); ?>

        <div class="form-group<?php if ($passwordRepeat->getMessages()): ?> has-warning<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="<?= $passwordRepeat->getName() ?>"
                       placeholder="<?= $this->getLocaliser()->key( 'repeat_password', 'Re-enter Password' ) ?>" name="<?= $passwordRepeat->getName() ?>"
                       value="<?= $passwordRepeat->getValue() ?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php $termsOfUse = $this->getElement('termsOfUse'); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="terms-of-use">
                <?php if ($termsOfUse->getMessages()): ?>
                    <p class="has-warning"><?php echo $termsOfUse->getMessages(); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <input type="checkbox" style="" value="<?= $termsOfUse->getValue() ?>"
                       id="<?= $termsOfUse->getName() ?>"
                       name="<?= $termsOfUse->getName() ?>" <?= $termsOfUse->getValue() ? "checked" : "" ?>>
                <label for="<?= $termsOfUse->getName() ?>"><?= $this->getLocaliser()->key( 'terms_of_use_label', $termsOfUse->getLabel()) ?></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $token = $this->getElement('token'); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="<?= $token->getName() ?>" value="<?= $token->getHash() ?>">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-trace"><?= $this->getLocaliser()->key( 'continue', 'Continue' ) ?></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isValid function from library/Zend/Form.php returns false while validating the csrf token. token is there but not sure it's valid or not. I can say it's invalid.